# Proof of ratio test correct?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Is this proof of the ratio test completely correct?

Let $0<r<r'<1$,
where $r= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}$. Then for $\epsilon=r'-r>0$, there exists $N \in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N \implies |\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|} -r|<r'-r=\epsilon$.Then $n \geq N \implies \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}<r'$. So that  $n \geq N \implies |a_{n+1}|<r'|a_n|$. Then $|a_{N+1}|<r'|a_N|,|a_{N+2}|<|a_N|(r')^2,...,|a_{N+k}|<|a_N|(r')^k$. Where $k \geq 1$. Then $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty} |a_N|(r')^{k-N+1}$ is a convergent geometric series. So $\sum_{k={N+1}}^{\infty} |a_k|$ converges by the comparison test. Since the convergence of the series does not depend on the first $N+1$ terms,  $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k|$ converges.$\implies \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges.

Suppose  $r= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|},r>1$. Then  there exists $N \in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N \implies |\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|} -r|<r-1=\epsilon$. Thus, $n \geq N \implies \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}>1$. Thus $n \geq N \implies |a_{n+1}|>|a_n|$. So that $\sum a_n$ diverges by the $n'th$ term test.

Comment: seems correct to me, you might as well consider the case of $r=1$. Alternatively one can use supremum and infimums to prove the root test and then one can note that the ratio test is nothing but a corollary of the root test.